# How to find mongodb data and log files location through command?

Tags: mongodb

How to find mongodb data and log files location through command?

like below SQL server command.

SELECT * FROM sys.database_files

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is probably with the `getCmdLineOpts` command:

```
db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({getCmdLineOpts:1})
```

This Mongo Shell command will first switch to the `admin` database then execute the `getCmdLineOpts` command. An alternative is the shell wrapper:

```
db.serverCmdLineOpts()
```

These will return the parsed command line options, which should contain both the data directory being used and the log path.

```
{
        "argv" : [
                "C:\\****\\3.4.10\\bin\\mongod.exe",
                "--dbpath",
                "C:\\****\\data",
                "--port",
                "27017",
                "--logpath",
                "C:\\****\\data\\mongod.log",
                "--bind_ip",
                "0.0.0.0"
        ],
        "parsed" : {
                "net" : {
                        "bindIp" : "0.0.0.0",
                        "port" : 27017
                },
                "storage" : {
                        "dbPath" : "C:\\****\\data"
                },
                "systemLog" : {
                        "destination" : "file",
                        "path" : "C:\\****\\data\\mongod.log"
                }
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

*Note: I obfuscated my paths, they do not normally contain `****`*.

You can see it provides both the raw values as well as the parsed values. If both command line options and config file options are specified on the command line, this will show the effective values being used by the process. Keep in mind there are [several extra options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#storage-options) that can effect where data is stored but this should get you on your way pretty quickly.

If you would like to know this information without using the Mongo Shell you will have to either grep the config file or look at the command line options of the running process, or both.

Answer (score 3):

You can view logs in mongoCLI also

to list all logs

```
> show logs
global
startupWarnings
```

show log content

```
> show log global
2018-01-30T09:14:10.305+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=778 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=ubuntu
2018-01-30T09:14:10.305+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.1
2018-01-30T09:14:10.305+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 025d4f4fe61efd1fb6f0005be20cb45a004093d1
```

data path will be printed on global log line 1, in my machine its `dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb`