# Error: MongoDB serves two different databases time to time when I start and stop the server

Tags: mongodb

When I start mongoDB server with `Mongod` command it serves my mongoDB databases. But some times I get different set of databases. Which means when I stop the server with `net stop MongoDB` and start server with `mongod` command 'A','B','C' databases are showed. Then when I stop and again and start the server 'D','E','F' databases are showed. 
What is actually happening. Is it running two instances or something time to time?

To be more clear

```
> show dbs
admin            0.000GB
codeProject      0.001GB
codeprojectData  0.017GB
config           0.000GB
local            0.000GB
projectData      0.285GB
```

[database 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoWVW.png)
 is what I get when I run mongod at path: `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin` 
when I run `net start MongoDB` at the same path I get

```
> show dbs
admin          0.000GB
config         0.000GB
local          0.000GB
projetDataNew  0.004GB
questions      0.000GB
```

[database 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg9bT.png)

Comment: Check which config files get loaded when u start your mongodb, u might have 2 config files and from mongod you might be triggering one and from service you might be triggering one....!

Comment: Something doesn't add up here.  If you are running a single instance of mongo and none of your databases are participating in ReplicaSets, I can't reason about how this would happen.  Perhaps if you included your means of asserting "its giving me different databases after restart", we may be able to help you understand what is actually happening.  Iike I want to see the output of `show dbs` as well as the basic shell command that got you there.

Comment: @PrashanthKumarB how can i find which config file s running?. Anyway there is only one `.cfg` file in my mongoDB bin directory.

Comment: thanks @BobKuhar, To be mote clear `> show dbs
admin            0.000GB
codeProject      0.001GB
codeprojectData  0.017GB
config           0.000GB
local            0.000GB
projectData      0.285GB` is what I get when I run mongod at path: `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin`                 when I run `net start MongoDB` at the same path I get `> show dbs
admin          0.000GB
config         0.000GB
local          0.000GB
projetDataNew  0.004GB
questions      0.000GB` this output

Comment: I think you need to figure out how to ask for the command line arguments mongod used when it started up. 
 I'm liking the theory that you are somehow using 2 different config files that are pointed at two different directories for the database files. 
 This answer speaks of some `db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand({getCmdLineOpts:1})` command you can run through the shell (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48507866/how-to-find-mongodb-data-and-log-files-location-through-command) .  There is almost certainly a way to do this with, like, `ps -elf` in bash or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this seems to be a config issue, to confirm this follow the below steps.

First open services in windows and check the properties of mongod command that you have installed, there you should be able to find the config file that you have provided while installing the service
Here is a screenshot of the view of mongodb service in services panel:
https://cdn.journaldev.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/MongoDB-Windows-Service.png

Once you have the path, try the below command:
{path to your mongod.exe} --config { Path of the config file that you just copied from the services panel }

Now if you do >show dbs; the listed databases will be the same as the one of net start Mongodb.

I think when u start mongod from bin it will just use a default config file from the mongodb root folder if you have installed in c:\ then it will be inside C:\MongoDB\mongod.conf.

I am 100% sure that when u start mongodb through mongod the data directory is different than when u start it through net start mongodb, hence different databases.

Always try to create your own config file and use that config file to run mongod, so that you know what options you have provided, don't use mongodb default config.

Follow the above steps and let me know how it goes ;)